# Is there any way to set up a keyboard shortcut for specific symbol in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

How to set up a keyboard shortcut for specific symbol in MS Excel? Let's say euro sign wanted on Ctrl+Alt+e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward way to do this (like there is in Word).

You can, however define a macro:<sup>1</sup>

1. (might not be needed) Click the `Office` button and select `Options`. Activate `Show Developer Options`. Close the popup.
2. Go to the `Developer` tab and click `Macros`.
3. Type in a name (e.g., `Euro`) and click `Create`.
4. Change the code to

   ```
   Sub Euro()
       Selection.Value = "€"
   End Sub
   ```

   and close the window.
5. Click options and select a keystroke sequence.

   As far as I know, you cannot choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

   You could, however, choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

<sup>1</sup> The instructions are for Excel 2007. They're also translated from Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

An AutoHotKey script can be used to do this. See the following guide.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21187/insert-any-special-character-with-a-single-keystroke/

The euro sign is one of the examples:

```
!e::
{
SendInput {€}
}
return
```